# django, celery : create worker per user basis

Tags: django, python-3.x, celery

Does it make sense (or not at all) to create a worker for each user logged in the website ?

The idea came as a user may have some long tasks to execute but must be allowed to cancel them at will. And as there is no warranty that any task stops when it's asked with :

```
revoke(task_id, terminate=True)
```

according to the [docs](https://docs.celeryproject.org/en/latest/reference/celery.app.control.html#celery.app.control.Control.revoke), even with [abortable tasks](https://docs.celeryproject.org/en/latest/reference/celery.contrib.abortable.html) (which does not allow to abort by task_id, with the risk also to terminate the worker.

So, to prevent that unknown outcome, I thought of that solution which allows fine control on task execution without risk.

Any advice is welcomed, thanks.

Comment: A worker per user would not solve this problem. Why do tasks need to be aborted/cancelled and what is the impact if they are not?

Comment: Task should be able to be cancelled because the user can just change his mind and if the task ends, it will just fill the database whith a lot of useless data. Could you please explain why this solution isn't actually one ?

Comment: The problem you are trying to solve is how to cancel/abort running tasks right? Having a worker per user adds complexity to your deployment but does not solve the issue. If you run an abortable task in a transaction, at the end (or in the middle) of the task you can raise an exception or rollback the transaction and the changes will not be committed to the DB

Comment: Yes this is the problem. The number of transactions could reach 10000 insertions or more (there is actually no limit), isn't it a bit risk-taking to allow that to finish just to rollback at the end ? Server load speaking.

Comment: How else would you abort the task though? If it is already running you have to rollback the transaction, 10,000 insertions isn't that much. As with all things, the only way to know is to test

Comment: The task runs and checks for its own id in a redis cache. After been revoked, if not found it ends the current loop. And then I can do the rollback. And even kill the worker if necessary. But you're right : the solution is testing it. :) Thanks

Comment: So either way the transaction has to be rolled back. I strongly suggest not creating a worker per user though, doing so adds complexity for very little benefit.

Comment: No worries! Hope you find the right solution :)